# Why doesn't ctrl+d work with this?

Tags: bash, regular-expression, file-descriptors

I wanted a simple way to process text in my clipboard without having to create a file. I tried using the following line:

```
awk '{print $1}' <(cat)
```

but I couldn't send cat the EOF character using ctrl+d like I normally do. I have a feeling it has something to do with a conflict of the file descriptor its creating to hold the data from cat, but I'm not entirely sure.

In the interim I'm using here documents, but it's ugly.

```
awk '{print $1}' <<KITTENMITTENStextblahKITTENMITTENS
```

The problem is it needs to be rather portable (across CLI commands). Any idea on a more elegant solution? Know why the cat line doesn't work?

Comment: What if you specify absolutely no parameter? `awk '{print $1}'`, Enter, paste with middle button, Ctrl-D.

Comment: I had originally wanted to do that, but i need to be able to use it with programs that only accept files as arguments :(

Comment: How are awk and cat related to your clipboard?  What value does `<(cat)` add?  Why not just `awk '{print $1}'` `ENTER`?

Comment: Use `-` if the command supports that syntax, or `/dev/fd/0` or `/dev/stdin` if your systems has that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `xclip` available on your machine? With `-o` parameter it outputs the current X selection to the standard output:

```
xclip -o | awk '{print $1}'
```

Comment: Thats a good idea, but i cant rely on xclip. I do a lot of work over ssh, and sometimes on Macs